# Find the number of permutations of {1,2,…, N} such that the sequence first increases and then decreases?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics, counting

For example, for N = 3.
The **permutations** are:

```
[1,3,2]
[2,3,1]
```

Note: `[1,2,3]` and `[3,2,1]` are not valid here because `[1,2,3]` increases but doesn't decreases and vice-versa for `[3,2,1]`.

I got this problem in TCS CodeVita 2017, they didn't even provide the editorial for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. All these permutations have number `N` somewhere in the middle
2. All numbers that less than `N` can be divided into two groups: left and right. The left group is in increasing order, the right group is in decreasing order.
3. The left and the right groups could not be empty.
4. The answer will be equal to the number of different left groups because this group should immediately be followed by `N` and all remaining numbers in decreasing order.
5. The left group can contain all numbers besides `N`. And it can neither be empty nor contain all `N-1` numbers.

Therefore, the answer is the number of subsets of numbers `{1, 2, ..., N-1}` minus two corner cases. That is `2^(N-1) - 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm would be as follows

1. The peak element would always be N
2. N cannot be at any of the 2 ends, so We can place it at N-2 positions
3. suppose N was at the i'th position, we can select i-1 numbers to be at the left side. these would be placed in a sorted manner, the other elements would simply be placed in reverse order after N
4. Number of ways to select i elements from n = nCi, we have to select (i-1) elements from (n-1) elements
5. N can be at any index from i = 2 to N-1 (assuming index starts from 1)
6. Answer would be

   (n-1)C1 + (n-1)C2 + (n-1)C3 + (n-1)C4 + ....(n-1)Cn-2 = **2^(n-1) - 2** // -2 handles the case for n-1C0 and n-1Cn-1

Comment: yes edited the answer, thanks we have to select i from n-1 elements since we have already place n at the i'th position